# Executing a snippet of code in the AlertView OK button declaration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

in my Alert View, there is two button, OK and Cancel. When the user click the OK button, the delegate method `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated` get called, and if the index is 0, then i get called to a method to execute some code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                                    message:@"Are you sure you want to exit"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" 

                                          otherButtonTitles: @"Cancel",nil]; 


    [alert show]; 
    [alert release];//release the reference
```

Delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        [self aMethod];
    }    
}

-(void)aMethod{

//Some useful code
}
```

Now, what i want to instead of all this, is to execute the code of the `aMethod` method in the AlertView directly, without referring to A delegate method and a method which get called, something like that:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                                message:@"Are you sure you want to exit"
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" //Put here some useful code

                                      otherButtonTitles: @"Cancel",nil];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What benefit would this bring?

Comment: Learning a new tip if it does exist, reducing the number of code line and number of calls ;)

Comment: This would be very, very, useful. Less code to be written, clearer code. And no need to tag your alerts when you have multiple alerts in your ViewController. Who knows iOS6...

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/zoul/Lambda-Alert, it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a pair of `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` subclasses that do exactly that. Grab them here:
https://github.com/rydermackay/RMActionSheet

Use them like this:

```
RMAlertView *alertView = [RMAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:nil];

[alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"
                       action:^{
                           NSLog(@"OK");
                       }];

[alertView addCancelButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             action:nil];
[alertView show];
```

**EDIT:**

From your comments it sounds like you're not familiar with blocks. Read this now. Seriously.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

This is a good one too:
http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html

Comment: You're welcome. Speaking from experience, it's easy to overuse blocks once you get the hang of them. Be careful ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible at this time (iOS 5.1). The AlertView class does not support blocks.

Comment: Hi, blocks you mean the snippet which start with `^` ?